# Get a user's geolocation in Meteor app

Tags: meteor, geolocation

right now I'm working on an app that relies heavily on user's geolocation. At this moment I only need to get an user's address through this user's latitude and longitude. To do this I use two packages: [mdg:geolocation](https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/tree/master/packages/mdg:geolocation) (to get latitude and longitude) and [meteor-google-reverse-geocode](https://github.com/JayMc/meteor-google-reverse-geocode) (to transfrom latitude and longitude into an address).
Right now I have the following code:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';
import { Geolocation } from 'meteor/mdg:geolocation';
import { reverseGeocode } from 'meteor/jaymc:google-reverse-geocode';

export default class Profile extends Component {
    setLocation() {
        var latLng = Geolocation.latLng();
        var lat = latLng.lat;
        var lng = latLng.lng;
        reverseGeocode.getSecureLocation(lat, lng, function(location) {
            Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {
                $set: {"profile.location": reverseGeocode.getAddrStr()}
            });
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col s4">
                        <User />
                    </div>
                    <button onClick={this.setLocation.bind(this)}>Set location</button>
                </div>
    </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I have a `User` component which displays user's location among other parameters but at first it should be getting this `location` param from registration and the log in (I'll implement sessions later), so I created a button that does the trick but only when I click it twice. With first click it doesn't get any info rather showing me an error in console but when I hit it second time it somehow works as I want, i.e getting the right address and then displaying it in my `User` component. Okay, it can grab the data but only if I click it twice which is not acceptable because I want to grab this data after registration or logging in, i.e with very first click, not the second one, but I still don't know how to do it. Any help or thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks for your time you dedicated to described problem!

**UPD**

After some research, I found that `Geolocation` function isn't reactive and it could take some time to load data, so I used `ReactiveVar` to make it reactive and `Tracker` to manually stop calculation when it's completed. Now my code looks like this:

```
setLocation() {
    var latLng = new ReactiveVar();
    Tracker.autorun(function(computation) {
        latLng.set(Geolocation.latLng());
        if (latLng.get()) {
            computation.stop();
            console.log(latLng);
            var lat = latLng.lat;
            var lng = latLng.lng;
            reverseGeocode.getSecureLocation(lat, lng, function(location) {
                Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {
                    $set: {"profile.location": reverseGeocode.getAddrStr()}
                });
            });
        }
    })
}
```

It computes `lan` and `lng` properties with first click but here comes another error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatted_address' of undefined` in `google-reverse-geocode.js` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay guys, I solved this problem. I took a look in `ReactiveVar` output and realized what was my mistake. See, the output contains and object `curValue` where `lan` and `lng` properties are stored, so to extract these properties I just had to call them explicitly like `latLng.curValue.lat`. Here's fixed function that works the way I described in my first post:

```
setLocation() {
    var latLng = new ReactiveVar();
    Tracker.autorun(function(computation) {
        latLng.set(Geolocation.latLng());
        if (latLng.get()) {
            computation.stop();
            console.log(latLng);
            var lat = latLng.curValue.lat;
            var lng = latLng.curValue.lng;
            reverseGeocode.getSecureLocation(lat, lng, function(location) {
                Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {
                    $set: {"profile.location": reverseGeocode.getAddrStr()}
                });
            });
        }
    })
}
```

Hope it helps someone!